# Chown in Linux and permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I wanted to give full permissions to some user in a folder.

I used for example

```
chown -R myuser /etc/myfolder
```

so , by doing `ls -l on /etc/myfolder` we can clearly see the owners of the file as: `myuser root`

The question is how can i remove myuser from being the owner of that folder? I used man chown and i searched on the web, but i cant find something useful . :S

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand the question. You did a `chown -R myuser` on the folder and now you're asking how to remove it again as the owner? Who should own the folder? A file or folder can only have *one* owner.

Comment: @slhck no, when i am doing ls -l theres myuser and root . I only want root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In traditional Unix permissions, a file or folder can only be owned by one user. When you do `chown -R myuser`, you set `myuser` as the owner of that particular file.

When doing an `ls -l`, the two names you see are the owner and the group the file belongs to, e.g. `myuser` being the owner and `root` being the group. Please read [Unix Permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions) for a little more info.

If you want the folder to be owned by root again, just do a `chown -R root` on it.

If you want a user to have full permissions on a folder, here are some possibilities you have:

- Let the user own the folder with `chown -R myuser`, and make sure the folder has read, write and execute access for that particular user, e.g. with `chmod u+rwx`.
- Add the user to a group that has read, write and execute access on the folder, e.g. `useradd -G root myuser`, where `root` is the name of the group, and `chmod g+rwx`. You also need to change the group of the folder with `chgrp -R root` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT -R means recursive, not remove.  Have you tried then:

```
chown -R root /etc/myfolder
```

Comment: i got the same answer already , but thanks :) Yes i know that -R stands for recursive , so it can affect all subfolders, not only the first one.

Comment: seconds late... sorry, it sounded from your post that that might have been a source of confusion.